# Unintend does not match while it seems absolutely correct

Tags: python

My code throws error I really can't understand why. There it is:

```
 File "alon.py", line 152
    fig.write_image("files/table_" + product_name + ".pdf")
                                                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

If I remove this line, it works. Can't see how it is unintended. It is under `if type(product_data) is dict:` statement. On the same level like the last line of code before it. What can cause such a behaviour ?

```
import MySQLdb
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import os
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Database connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="abc9110033969",
                     db="alon")

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
one_week = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
two_week = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=14)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
three_week = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=21)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
four_week = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=28)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Functions
def load_post_views(table, today, one_week, two_week, three_week, four_week):

    product_views_dict = dict()

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT client_id, product_id, referrer, `date`" +
        " FROM " + table + 
        " WHERE `date`>='"+four_week+"'")

    social_dict = {
                    "facebook": 0,
                    "twitter": 0,
                    "instagram": 0,
                    "linkedin": 0,
                    "pinterest": 0,
                    "website": 0,
                }
    for x in range(0, cursor.rowcount):

        row = cursor.fetchone()
        network = ""
        period = ""
        client_id = row[0]
        product_id = row[1]
        referrer = row[2]
        date = str(row[3])

        email_cursor = db.cursor()
        email_cursor.execute("SELECT address FROM c8ty_connections_email WHERE entry_id=" + str(client_id))
        email = email_cursor.fetchone()

        product_cursor = db.cursor()
        product_cursor.execute("SELECT post_title FROM c8ty_posts WHERE id=" + str(product_id))
        product_name = product_cursor.fetchone()

        # Add client ID key
        if client_id not in product_views_dict:
            product_views_dict[client_id] = dict()

        # Add product ID key to client ID parent key 
        if product_id not in product_views_dict[client_id]:
            product_views_dict[client_id][product_id] = {
                today + " - " + one_week: social_dict,
                one_week + " - " + two_week: social_dict,
                two_week + " - " + three_week: social_dict,
                three_week + " - " + four_week: social_dict
            }

        # Find referrer
        if "facebook" in referrer:
            network = "facebook"
        elif "twitter" in referrer:
            network = "twitter"
        elif "instagram" in referrer:
            network = "instagram"
        elif "linkedin" in referrer:
            network = "linkedin"
        elif "pinterest" in referrer:
            network = "pinterest"
        else:
            network = "website"

        # Check view period
        if date <= today and date > one_week:
            period = today + " - " + one_week
        if date <= one_week and date > two_week:
            period = one_week + " - " + two_week
        if date <= two_week and date > three_week:
            period = two_week + " - " + three_week
        if date <= three_week and date > four_week:
            period = three_week + " - " + four_week

        product_views_dict[client_id][product_id][period][network] += 1 
        product_views_dict[client_id]["email"] = email[0]
        product_views_dict[client_id][product_id]["product"] = product_name[0]

    return product_views_dict

# Init
product_views_dict = load_post_views("an_product_view", today, one_week, two_week, three_week, four_week)
brochure_views_dict = load_post_views("an_brochure_view", today, one_week, two_week, three_week, four_week)

for clinetID, product_info in product_views_dict.items():

    client_email = product_info["email"]

    for productID, product_data in product_info.items():

        if type(product_data) is dict:

            product_name = product_data['product']
            table_data = [
                [
                    today      + " - " + one_week,
                    one_week   + " - " + two_week,
                    two_week   + " - " + three_week,
                    three_week + " - " + four_week,
                    today      + " - " + four_week
                ]
            ]

            for network in ["website", "facebook", "twitter", "instagram", "linkedin", "pinterest"]:
                table_data.append([
                    product_data[today + " - " + one_week][network],
                    product_data[one_week + " - " + two_week][network],
                    product_data[two_week + " - " + three_week][network],
                    product_data[three_week + " - " + four_week][network],
                    sum([
                        int(product_data[today + " - " + one_week][network]),
                        int(product_data[one_week + " - " + two_week][network]), 
                        int(product_data[two_week + " - " + three_week][network]), 
                        int(product_data[three_week + " - " + four_week][network])
                    ])
                ])

            fig = make_subplots(rows=5, cols=2)
            # Create product table
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Table(
                    header=dict(values=["Period", "Website", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Instagram", "LinkedIn", "Pinterest", "Total"]),
                    cells=dict(values=table_data)
                )
            )

            # Craete folder if doesn't exist
            if not os.path.exists("files"):
                os.mkdir("files")

            # Write pdf
            fig.write_image("files/table_" + product_name + ".pdf")

db.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your source file that you aren't mixing spaces and tabs? It should be consistent, and only one or the other. I recommend spaces to [comply with PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: The problem was these ` + product_name + ` spaces ... Thank you!